# Drawing shape programmatically with part corners rounded only

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

Problem here is to draw this kind of shape in onDraw method.

I've tried using `Path` and `CornerPathEffect` but the bottom corners need to be sharp, so it was not working solution.

[image]

Comment: I think you looking for [Linear Gradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html) ? An example is [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/09/lineargradient-example.html)

Comment: Thanks vini, I got the gradient working all right, just need top corners rounded anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Problem here is to draw this kind of shape in onDraw method.

Modifying the values for your case:

```
Path p = new Path();
Paint paintN = new Paint();
paintN.setAntiAlias(true);
paintN.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paintN.setColor(Color.YELLOW);  
p.moveTo(40, 60);
p.quadTo(40, 40, 60, 40);   
p.lineTo(180, 40);
p.quadTo(200, 40, 200, 60);
p.lineTo(200, 90);
p.lineTo(40, 200);
p.close();
canvas.drawPath(p, paintN);
```