# Draw image on canvas with 2 rounded corners

Tags: android, canvas, draw

Hello i have read Romain Guy's tutorial here: http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/
It's great but it assumes that user want to draw image with all rounded corners. I want to round only two bottom corners to make nice image. I would like to do it in code.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878804/drawing-shape-programmatically-with-part-corners-rounded-only

Comment: @DerGolem thank you, after some fun with matrix, and shaders it's working fine.